# Installing Propel 2.0 on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, propel

I'm trying to install Propel 2.0 on my Mavericks (OS X 10.9). I followed the Git approach from [the installation instructions](http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html), thus:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/propelorm/Propel2 vendor/propel
```

However, whenever I want to test my Propel installation by typing "propel" in Terminal, I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder' not found in /Users/Dawid/vendor/propel/bin/propel.php on line 16
```

What is the easiest way to make it work?

Comment: It's probably best if you explain how you set it up in your question, rather than referring people to a link. Questions should be self-contained, and in any case there are three approaches (Composer, Git, tarball) listed there.

Comment: @halfer done :)
Do someone has any idea? I need solution quickly (deadline)

Comment: (Best not to request urgency here, @Dav - it encourages close votes!)

Comment: Since there is no git submodules in use here, it looks like you are forced to use Composer to install your dependencies. Try additionally running the Composer instructions (install composer, then run the Composer console command).

Comment: Unfortunately I have problem with installing via Composer. I've install composer with $ wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar and create composer.json with {
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": ">= 2.0"
    }
}
and when I tried to $ php composer.phar install 

it says: The requested package propel/propel could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: Ah, did you create your own composer.json file? That wasn't necessary, since Propel already has one. I should have been clearer: I meant to `cd` to your Propel folder and just run the `wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar` and then `php composer.phar install` from there.

Comment: When I tried this i get this message: 
`[RuntimeException] vendor does not exist and could not be created`.

Comment: Hmm, not very specific, is it? Maybe `sudo php composer.phar install`? Permissions issue, possibly?

Comment: That gives me nothing to go on, unfortunately. You could always download Symfony Components, and download them to your standard PHP include path, so that Propel finds them. But I might be inclined to hack around with Composer for a bit longer...

Comment: Sorry, sudo actually helps :) thanks! `propel` command also works! Thanks a lot. You can post an answer and I'll vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you had cloned the Propel Git repository, and were finding that the console command does not work out of the box. This is because the repo was missing its *dependencies* - other libraries that Propel itself uses to work.

In the olden days, we'd just do `git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive`, and boom, all (Git) dependencies would be set up and downloaded. Now the hipster kids have switched to Composer, there's more faffing to be done (though, to be fair, it can retrieve deps from a much wider range of sources).

To install from Composer, one would normally do:

```
wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```

However, in your case, `sudo` was required for the last step - perhaps you're working in a folder to which your usual user does not have write access?